# Como cambiar el formato de fecha en VB SSRS

Tags: date, vb, ssrs, date-format

tengo este codigo y me gustaria poder cambiar el formato de la fecha por el siguiente "YYYY-MM-DD", el codigo me arroja automaticamente este formato: "MM/DD/YYYY 12:00:00 AM". Y para los que se pregunten que hace este codigo pues primero detecta si el dia actual el lunes, si es verdadero a la actual fecha le resta una semana para obtener la fecha del lunes pasado- y en caso de que no sea lunes traer la fecha de un dia antes.

```
=IIF(WeekdayName(DatePart("w", Today))="Monday",DateAdd("d", -7, Today),DateAdd("d", 0, Today))
```

Intente con el siguiente codigo pero me marca este error "Argument 'DateValue' cannot be converted to type 'Date'"

```
=IIF(WeekdayName(DatePart("w", Today))="Monday",DateAdd("d", -7, Format(Today,"YYYY-MM-DD")),DateAdd("d", 0, Format(Today,"YYYY-MM-DD")))
```

Bueno espero que me puedan ayudar, no es necesario que el codigo sea igual solo que me traiga los resultados que les comentaba con el formato que les mencione, Gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por defecto, el formato de fecha que te maneja tu SSRS sera por el paquete de lenguaje que tenga tu sistema operativo, en este caso si lo tienes en espanol, instala la version en ingles y ponla por defecto.
Te recomiendo usar now() en lugar de today si es que te interesa la hora, aqui la base

[Diferencias entre now() y today()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34177786/what-is-the-difference-between-today-and-now-in-ssrs)

Puedes probar estas soluciones:

1. Convierte a formato de fecha el parametro que le estas dando y ahi aplicas la salida que deseas ej.

   `=Format(CDate(now()), "MM-dd-yyyy hh:mm.ss")`
2. En algunas ocasiones es menos complicado mandarlo con el formato correcto desde el origen de datos (si estas usando sql server puedes convertirlo al formato deseado)